# Question about Expected Value Problem

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to solve this problem:

[image: Expected Value Problem]

According to the book, the solution is $741

Here is my reasoning.

The expected value formula is:

[image: Formula]

In our case f(x) is defined from 1.

As the problem says that T=3.  I am integrating from 1 to 3.

We have this integral that calculated with Wolfram Alpha:

[image: Integral]

E(X)= 4/3

Thus L=(4/3)/3 = 4/9

The Bonus would be (0.5-(4/9))(300,000/30)= $556

However, the answer is $741.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get your bonus if $\frac {x}{T} < 0.5$ or $x < 1.5$

bonus formula:

$(0.5 - L)(\frac {T}{30})\\
L = \frac {x}{T}\\
(0.5 - \frac {x}{T})(\frac {T}{30})\\
(\frac {T}{60} - \frac {x}{30})$

Expected bonus $ = \int_1^{1.5} (\frac {T}{60} - \frac {x}{30})(3x^{-4}) dx$

Comment: One question. Would be possible to get the same result using the expected value of x?

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. However, my question is why does not work to plug that value in the bonus formula?

Comment: $E[X]$ in with the condition that the salesman receives a bonus? or just $E[X]$ in general?  $E[X] = \int_0^{\infty} 3 x^{-3} = -\frac {3}{2} x^{-2}|_1^\infty = \frac 32.  E[X|X<\frac 32] = \int_1^{\frac 32} 3 x^{-3} = \frac 32 x^{-2}|_1^{\frac 32} = \frac 32 (1-\frac 49) = \frac {5}{6}$

Comment: Sorry, I answered before I thought it through...

Comment: I plugged 5/6 in the bonus formula and I did not get $741. Why? Is the integration of the bonus formula the only way to do it?

Comment: The bonus is a constant (fraction of the total premiums paid conditional that losses are sufficiently small, less a fraction of the the expected losses conditional that losses are sufficiently small).    $\frac 1{30}(\frac {3}{2}\cdot P(X\le \frac 32) - E[X|X\le \frac 32])(\$100,000)$

Answer (score 1):

The bonus is: $\dfrac{(0.5-L)T}{30}$ if $L<0.5$ and otherwise $0$, where $L=X/T$.

So the integration boundaries should be $1$ to $T/2$.  (ie $1.5$ at $T=3$)

Comment: Thank for you much! Wonderful answer!

Comment: One question. Would be possible to get the same result using the expected value of x?